# Super Admin unable to reset user password without knowing current pasword

Tags: password

So a staff member (belonging the 'editor' group) recently left, and we'd like to update the password to a dummy one but I can't seem to be able to do it as EE is asking me for the current password.

Any idea how?

Installed EE version is 2.8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language is somewhat unclear on that screen. What you actually need to enter is *your* current password, not the *user's* current password.

Comment: If you dont want to reassign the entries to another editor. I would also recommend creating a new member group that does not have CP access to prevent the user from going through the password reset flow to log back in.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just ban or delete the account?

To answer your question, one method would be to run a MySQL query update on the members table row of that member_id and insert nonsense into the password and salt fields, or better yet, take a look at the Auth library hash_password method and generate a usable password hash and salt and insert that.